# Prove that a set is countable by defining a bijective function.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S = 5\mathbb{Z}^+ = \{5n|n \in Z^+\}$ where $Z^+$ denotes the nonnegative integers.

Prove that $S$ is countable by defining a bijective function $f:Z^+ \to S$.

I proved that it is bijective by letting $m$ and $n$ be in $Z^+$ such that $f(m) = f(n)$. Then $5m = 5n$ which shows $m = n$ hence it is injective.
The by letting $y \in S, x = \frac{y}{5} = n \in Z^+$ such that $f(n) = f(\frac{y}{5}) = 5(\frac{y}{5}) = y \in S$. Hence, it is surjective.

But now, how do I define a bijective *function* from all of this? Thank you!

Comment: You have essentially defined the function you want. Look at your argument for showing $f$ is injective. You say that $f(m) = f(n)$ implies $5m=5n$. Aren't you saying $f(m)=5m$ by doing so? This is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to *define* a bijective function $f$ from $Z^+$ to $S$, that is, give an explicit "rule" or formula for the relationship.

The obvious choice (which I guess you identified but didn't explicitly show) is $f:Z^+ \rightarrow S : f(n) = 5n$, which is clearly bijective since the inverse $f^{-1}:S \rightarrow Z^+ : f^{-1}(x) = x/5$ exists (or you can prove it proving that it is surjective and injective, using the arguments you showed in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Proving $f$ to be a function is like proving it to be injective and surjective, but in reverse order. It takes care of all of the "obvious" properties we take for granted. We want to show that for any $x$ in the domain (here, $x\in Z^+$), that there exists $y$ in the domain ($y\in S$) such that $f(x)=y$. This should be easy.

We also need to show well-definedness of $f$; that if $f(x)=y_1$ and $f(x)=y_2$, then $y_1=y_2$. This seems obvious, but I could define a relation $R$ on $Z^+\times S$ by $R(z,s)$ if $z|s$ (that is, $R$ is the relation "divides), but this relation would not be a function, since $R(1,5)$ and $R(1,10)$. In this case, however, it should be easy to show.

As an aside, well-definedness most often comes up when domain is a set of equivalence classes, in which case you need to show that $f$ acts the same on any element of the equivalence class as it would on any other element of the same class.